# How come random is a wave?

Tags: wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, terminology

In Schrodinger's theory of the atom, an electron does not move on a circular path. Its motion is in 3D and its random. It could be anywhere in space. How come they named it to wave form? If it's random, how can we talk about wave here?

Comment: This question isn't very clear. You may have an interesting question with an interesting set of answers, but the way this question is worded right now doesn't make it clear what you're asking. Mind rewording this?

Comment: Schrodinger said the electron can be any where in orbital. At random place. He gave equation for probability distribution of finding an electron in orbital. Why he named it wave function. Why wave. The defintion of wave is not deal with random it. Wave is periodic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its called a wave function because it comes in the form $\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2} = k \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}$ (or rather, the multidimensional equivalent of that).  That kind of equation models all sorts of waves, the way you and I think of waves.

The randomness comes when one wishes to make an observation of the particle's state.  The act of measuring it results in a value which is drawn from a random distribution.  The probability of finding the particle in any given state (such as the probability of finding an electron in any particular region) can be derived from the wave function.

Answer (score 1):

This is perhaps the deepest mystery in understanding quantum mechanics, and the answer is generally only explained in postgraduate level mathematics.

We can start by observing that there is randomness in almost any experimental result. Classically, this is understood in terms of experimental accuracy, but it is also a general principle on which we can base the mathematical foundation of quantum mechanics. We can then define probabilities for results given known initial conditions. We can then define a probability amplitude to obey the Born rule, and we can define a superposition principle to model weighted logical OR (the result of a measurement may be one thing OR another).

To preserve the probability interpretation under time evolution places mathematical constraints on the probability amplitude, namely unitarity of time evolution satisfying the condition of Stone's theorem (proved by Marshall Stone in 1932). From this the Schrodinger equation follows as a simple corollary. The Schrodinger equation is a wave equation, so it follows that probability amplitudes obey wave mechanics.

I have given details and references in [The Hilbert space of conditional clauses](https://arxiv.org/abs/1205.4607) and in my books.